# Error : Multiple annotations found at this line:

Tags: android, xml

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - [Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute 
     on image

and my xml Code is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/iv_Seelct_Image"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/select_image"/>
  <GridView  
          android:id="@+id/gridview"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:columnWidth="270dp"
          android:numColumns="auto_fit"
          android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
          android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
          android:gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xml file must have root layout like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout Like that

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<your imageview>
<your gridview>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:contentDescription="@string/desc"` as an attribute to the ImageView.

Comment: Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:contentDescription) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/accessibility-are-you-serving-all-your.html)

Comment: this is used for "[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image" when this type of warning comes